# Markdown Extra text align

Tags: php, html, markdown, text-alignment

How do i create text align in Markdown Extra syntax without using HTML tags(i need to simplify post typing for users)? Or how do i extend Markdown PHP Extra to add some new rules like this:

```
->here is centered text <- to <center> </center>
```

sorry for my english

Comment: What have you tried? The source is available at https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/extra/markdown.php for you to hack upon.

Comment: Be aware that the `<center>` tag is deprecated. Instead, you should use a styled `<span>` or other element with a `text-align` property.

Comment: I need to use only markdown extra in something "like forum reply" without html. Does markdown extra have some extentions to add text align, or how could i write the rule for parser? I don't fully understand source code. Where could i find some example on extend Markdown Extra?